# Getting data from Ziptastic using asp.net not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have below code but nothing happens when a zip code is entered, what is wrong here?

**html**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtZipCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>        
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**script**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[id$='txtZipCode']").keyup(function () {
            var el = $(this);

            if (el.val().length === 5) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://zip.getziptastic.com/v2/US/" + el.val(),
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (result, success) {
                        $("input[id$='txtCity']").val(result.city);
                        $("input[id$='txtState']").val(result.state);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps your ajax call is not succeeding? Have you attempted to debug this?

Comment: Why don't you share the fiddle?

Comment: @DanielCook http://jsfiddle.net/7VtHc/117/

Comment: Unfortunately, your fiddle doesn't work in my browser (IE10) hopefully it'll work for someone else.

Comment: @DanielCook Now that you mention that, I realized that just work on Chrome :( any idea on how to make it work on IE, mine is IE8

Comment: I have been searching for a definitive answer since I realized the problem. Lots of questions mention it but nothing authoritative yet. Perhaps someone needs to ask specifically about that.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206782/ajax-call-not-working-in-ie8